# XDebug profiling in PHP - can't get output

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I've got a strange issue.  I've setup XDebug to profile a PHP application we're working on.  I believe everything is setup correctly but I get no output when I run it.  My configuration looks like this:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so
[XDebug]
xdebug.profiler_append = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0 (I've tried this both on and off)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/debug/xdebug/profiler_output_dir"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%p"
```

All the `phpinfo()` settings match up like they should.  The permissions on the output directory are set to 777 right now just so I can test it.  I've tried using a directory under public_html as well but no luck.  The URL I'm using to launch the profiler is:

```
http://example.com/my_page.php?XDEBUG_PROFILE
-or-
http://example.com/my_page.php?XDEBUG_PROFILE=1
```

Neither works.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!  This app has a 5-6 second page load time and I haven't been able to trace it through code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comment out `xdebug.profiler_output_dir` and `xdebug.profiler_output_name` and see whether you can find the output under `/tmp/`.

Comment: Hamid,

Turns out you were on the right track.  I'd forgotten to put the full path to the output directory.  Here's the final solution:
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="/home/username/debug/xdebug/profiler_output_dir"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%s.%H"

Answer (score 18):

There is also problem with /tmp folders on some distributions, i couldnt get output on centos 7 and then i found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173456)

So, i have set

> xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/home/jirka/profile

`chmod 777 /home/jirka/profile` and its ok now.

Comment: There's more information about that `PrivateTmp` setting [here](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/). It "sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts a private `/tmp` directory inside it, that is not shared by processes outside of the namespace. This means that processes running with this flag would see a different and unique `/tmp` from the one users and other daemons sees or can access."

Comment: Thanks for this.
It turns out my OpenSUSE 13.1 has the same configuration and moving the profiler output elsewhere solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Another possible cause of this issue is the permissions on the folder of profiler_output_dir.

Adding write permissions to the group and owner resolved the issue for me:

```
sudo chmod go+w /home/dimitris/cachegrind/
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, beware of access restrictions, such as access rights, groups, owner and SElinux...

Comment: Indeed. Had same problem with apache not being able to write to defined user directory because of permissions

Answer (score 1):

The full path was required, not just the path:

```
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="/home/username/debug/xdebug/profiler_output_dir"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%s.%H"
```

Comment: Note: This was the solution provided by the OP in their question.