# Xdebug and No Profiling Output

Tags: php, cakephp, profiling, xdebug

This is a similar problem to [XDebug profiling in PHP - can't get output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450500/xdebug-profiling-in-php-cant-get-output) but mine is on windows and I have the full path specified (which solved his problem)

**I am not getting any output even though I have enabled the profiler.** Below is a copy of xdebug setup (I have indented all the options that have been uncommented.) - *Please note that xdebug is working fine as Ii have been getting the standard xdebug errors.* If it make any difference I am using xampp, cakephp, php 5.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

;xdebug.auto_trace = 0
;xdebug.collect_includes = 1
;xdebug.collect_params = 0
;xdebug.collect_return = 0
;xdebug.collect_vars = "Off"
;xdebug.default_enable = "On"
;xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
;xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
;xdebug.dump.COOKIE = ""
;xdebug.dump.FILES = ""
;xdebug.dump.GET = ""
;xdebug.dump.POST = ""
;xdebug.dump.REQUEST = ""
;xdebug.dump.SERVER = ""
;xdebug.dump.SESSION = ""
;xdebug.dump_globals = 1
;xdebug.dump_once = 1
;xdebug.dump_undefined = 0
;xdebug.extended_info = 1
;xdebug.file_link_format = ""
;xdebug.idekey = ""
;xdebug.manual_url = "http://www.php.net"
;xdebug.max_nesting_level = 100
;xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
    xdebug.profiler_append = 0
    xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
    xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
    xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
    xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%R::%u"
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
    xdebug.remote_enable = 0
    xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
    xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.remote_log = "none"
;xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000
;xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
;xdebug.show_local_vars = 0
;xdebug.show_mem_delta = 0
;xdebug.trace_format = 0
;xdebug.trace_options = 0
    xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.trace_output_name = "trace.%c"
;xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
;xdebug.var_display_max_data = 512
;xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 3
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think it's to do with the "xdebug.profiler_output_name" setting

I copied your config, but changed the value of "xdebug.profiler_output_name" like below

```
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
```

And it worked OK, but with your existing value of "xdebug.profiler_output_name" it didn't

I think it's to do with it not allowing colons in the output file name

Hope this helps/solves your problem!

**Edit:**
Just for reference, here are the full settings that work

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

**Edit 2:**

Since the answer is getting a lot of hits, just thought I'd explain why. In the config file in the question, the `output_name` contains a `:` character, which is an allowed character in a filename on Linux, but not Windows.

Comment: Thanks! That save my life. I feel it is a common problem under Windows .

Comment: worked like a charm.. I had the default xampp value: "xdebug_profile.%R::%u"

Comment: Thanks!! This was the problem for me in windows too. Weird that the default xampp xdebug settings don't work for windows, you'd think they would have tested them or fixed them by now.