# Trace Statements in PHP

Tags: php

In C#/.NET, I can use Trace.Write or Debug.Write to output application specific diagnostics.  What would be the equivalent in PHP?  echo is outputting to my web page which I don't want.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663077/xdebug-and-no-profiling-output and http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Comment: A lot of people aren't familiar with C#. Could you explain what those commands do / what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write data to the error_log using [`error_log()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) Via the second argument you can select the type of logging you want, such as file logging, system logging or even email.