# apache xdebug & webgrind Output Not writing Log File

Tags: php, debugging, mamp, xdebug, webgrind

I'm using Mamp and after install webgrind the Xdebug output is not been  written in the proper file: not in the selected path (/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log) nor in the tmp folder.

Apache Error Log says:
[info] [client 127.0.0.1] (32)Broken pipe: core_output_filter: writing data to the network, which I thing is related..

PHP.ini is:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log"
```

And in there, all log related lines (error_reporting, log_errors,...) have the value
    `MAMP_php_log_errors_MAMP`

I`ve tried the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076743/xdebug-profiler-does-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450500/xdebug-profiling-in-php-cant-get-output) with no luck; 
Tried different log file paths, different PHP versions, checked permissions, and different lines in .ini file; the broken pipe thing does not clarify anything...

Debug.log files are created by wordpress are written just fine, an so on the display

Any suggestion?

Mamp 2.2
PHP 5.5.3
Webgrind 1.0

Comment: cachegrind.out files are created fine at /var/temp.